# How to understand PriorityQueue?

Tags: java

Here is My Code

```
 import java.util.*;
    public class PriorityPuzzle{
        public static void main(String []args){
            PriorityQueue<Integer> prq = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();  
            for ( int i = 10; i > 0; i-- ){  
                  prq.add (i); 
                  System.out.print(i+" , ");
            }  

            System.out.println ( "\n Initial priority queue values are: "+ prq);    
        }  
    }
```

**Result**

[image]

I donnot know why the after Priority the queue become
{1,2,5,4,3,9,6,10,7,8}

Comment: I wonder what is logical that sort from `10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1` to `1,2,5,4,3,9,6,10,7,8` –

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`toString()` method for `PriorityQueue`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/util/PriorityQueue.java) just inherits [the one from `AbstractCollection`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#AbstractCollection.toString%28%29). This just iterates over the items in the collection and prints them.

From the docs [for the iterator of PriorityQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html):

> The Iterator provided in method iterator() is not guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order. If you need ordered traversal, consider using Arrays.sort(pq.toArray()).

So printing the queue doesn't print the items in the order that you would get them if you retrieved them from the queue one at a time.

Comment: I wonder what is logical that sort from 10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1 to 1,2,5,4,3,9,6,10,7,8

Comment: Apparently, according to the docs and markspace, the Java `PriorityQueue` is based on a [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)).

Answer (score 3):

The docs say that this priority queue is based on a priority heap.  The docs also don't mention that `toString()` is overridden by this class.  `PriorityQueue` actually uses the toString method from `AbstractCollection`.

I'm going to guess that therefore `toString()` doesn't bother to print the elements in order, it just uses some arbitrary internal order dependent on the heap.  If you want to print the elements in order, you'll have to use an `Iterator` or something similar and print them yourself.

Comment: Iterating won't work, either. From the docs: "The Iterator provided in method iterator() is not guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order. If you need ordered traversal, consider using Arrays.sort(pq.toArray())."

Comment: Seriously?  Crap, I should read the docs myself.  Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: I wonder what is logical that sort from 10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1 to 1,2,5,4,3,9,6,10,7,8

Comment: @Sheldon It's not logical, it's *arbitrary*.  See yshavit's comment and augray's answer.  Also, read the docs (unlike me).